# Drupal Facebook Connect functionality

Tags: facebook, module, drupal

I have tried to implement Drupal Connect with Facebook functionality via the fbconnect module. I have installed and set up the plugin. When I click on the Facebook button the new popup window is opened and it requires my Facebook credentials. After I enter those, instead of just simply logging in to my site, Drupal asks of me to create a new account for Drupal.

Is there any way to just connect with my Facebook account without creating a new one on the Drupal site?

Answer (score 1):

RPX works the same way.

I believe you would have to modify the code to grab the returned data from Facebook and simulate a user creation with user_save, then automatically log them in, bypassing the Drupal login. Drupal needs a way of tracking that user on the site which is why that occurs.

I don't think the modules are quite there yet, though. Thanks for pointing that out, because I will have to come up with something like this.